# Edit text file with html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make a system through html or javascript with which I can edit .txt files.

Comment: Try adding more detail to your question. It's a bit unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local file access with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

One of the *perks* to JavaScript is not being able to access client side storage easily. Unfortunately you will need to either provide more information on your goal, or choose another language.

Comment: Or how to edit any text from site? like page title before is "123" and after is "124"